# How to overload BasicType.ToString()

Tags: vb.net, overloading, tostring

I would like to overload the `ToString()` method for an `Integer` but only within a certain class (i.e. when I call `Integer.ToString` within `Foo` class it uses my overload, when I call it outside of `Foo` class it uses the standard method)

Firstly, is that possible?

Secondly My reason for wanting to overload this is so that I can have it make a string of the hex values of each byte of the integer with some pretty formatting, e.g. if my integer is `&HA55A` Then `MyInteger.ToString` will return a string = `"5A A5"` (Little-endian). Is overloads the way to go? Or an override, or an extension?

Thirdly I have tried overloading as follows but the call in the same class still seems to use the normal `ToString()` meaning it results in the "42330" instead.

```vb
Public Class Foo
    Public Sub Bar ()
        Dim MyInt As Integer = 42330
        Dim BetterString As New String(MyInt.ToString) ' Should use the ToString() below 
        'to give "5A A5" not "42330"
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Function ToString(i As Integer) As String
        Dim a As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(i)
        Dim RetVal As New System.Text.StringBuilder(a.Length * 3)
        Dim ByteStr As String
        Dim Last As Integer = a.Length - 1

        For Index As Integer = 0 To Last
            ByteStr = New String(Conversion.Hex(a(Index)))
            If ByteStr.Length = 1 Then
                RetVal.Append("0")
            End If
            RetVal.Append(ByteStr)
            If i <> Last Then
                RetVal.Append(" ")
            End If
        Next
        Return RetVal.ToString
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Wiz
    Public Sub Pop
        Dim MyInt As Integer = 42330
        Dim MyString As NewString(MyInt.ToString) ' Should always be "42330"
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm pretty much a newb to VB.Net so I'm still grappling with the best way of achieving what I want with it.

Comment: You can't overload a member of a type that you're not writing the code for yourself.  What you could do is write an extension method, which you can then call as though it was an instance method.  That will be accessible anywhere within your project though.

Comment: I don't know would this suggestion help You but, why not wrote `function` (for example Int2String) into `module` and it's accessible in whole project. It's just my opinion. btw. what is that `a`?

Comment: @nelek Whoops fixed the `a` and `i` variables now, ta

Comment: @jmcilhinney so if I still wanted to use the original Integer.ToString() somewhere else in my project I'd have to name the new extension method to something else, right? Would kind of defeat part of the purpose of overloading, so I guess I can just make my own function within the `Foo` class and save myself the hassle of trying to be clever.

Comment: @Toby interested, return `5A A5 00 00`... Like in my prev. comment, my suggestion is write that function in `module` and use anywhere in project. btw. instead `Bytes()` is `Byte()` ;) That is my suggestion, I'm out.

Comment: No, you can still name the extension method `ToString`. If you were to actually overload the `ToString` method in a type then you'd have to specify at least one parameter and the same would apply in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an extension method.  Something like:

```
Module IntegerExtensions
    <Extension()> 
    Public Function ToHex(ByVal i As Integer) As String
        Return Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Hex( i )
    End Function 
End Module
```

Then call ToHex wherever you want the hexadecimal value.

You can't really change the ToString for Integer, and even if you could it wouldn't be a good idea - it would be confusing.  It would be better to have two separate methods and use ToHex when you want a hex string, and ToString when you want the regular string.  It also makes the code more readable.  When you see ToHex or ToHexadecimalString or ToHexString you will know what the code is doing.  Even if you did get it working when someone saw ToString it wouldn't be obvious to them that they would be getting a hexadecimal string.

Comment: Just need `Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices`, too. I learned  something new :)